# AS3 AIR in app loading screen

Tags: actionscript-3, air, starling-framework

I was wondering if someone could share some thoughts about how best to implement an in app loading screen.

I am building a mobile app using Starling and Feathers UI for iOS and Android and some times when a menu item is clicked to go to a new page it takes a few seconds due to the components that are on the stage on the called page. I would like to display a generic 'loading...please wait' screen which will have a message and a loading spinner which will be shown every time a new page is requested.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it's actually done, while you're directing your user to the frame, you make the loader MovieClip visible, the loader movie clip is a simple animation, like this: 
[loader http://www.pockettorah.com/wp-content/app/images/loader.gif](http://www.pockettorah.com/wp-content/app/images/loader.gif)

1. Make a movieclip and in instance name name it loader, and animate it like above
2. At the top of your code, say `loader.visible = false;`
3. In your code, after `gotoAndStop`/`gotoAndPlay` or whatever, say `loader.visible = true;`
   There is no real way of displaying this, usually it's just a fake animation that displays while the data is being processed.

Comment: Thanks, thats the method I thought I would have to take so thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

Its called a splash screen, it can be a simple jpeg. Adobe help [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WSa122979b4619725672e48c412a3e152164-8000.html)

Comment: Oh, its maybe flex only. sorry.